# How to get only two options from dropdown list through an array using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Here I tried to push my select tag values into array but there is some error with the array part.
In the code I have two same conditions, so when I enter 5 digits in the input field, then it should show me only two values rather than showing whole list and it is only possible with an array. Can someone help me out ?

CODE:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(document).keyup(function(){ 
            var arr=[];
            $("#txtFirstNo").on("input", function() {
                
                if ( $("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '') ) {
                    arr.push($("#selResult").val("aaa"));
                    //alert("hey");
                }
                if ( $("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^(\d{5})$/, '')) {
                    arr.push($("#selResult").val("bbb"));
                }
                if ( $("#txtFirstNo").val().match(/^(\d{10})$/, '')) {
                    arr.push($("#selResult").val("ccc"));
                }
                $('#selResult').text(arr);
            });
          });
        
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>

Number :
      <input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" />
      Options :
<select id="selResult" >
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>
</select>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple selected values for multi-select picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718354/how-to-set-multiple-selected-values-for-multi-select-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes to your code:

- use `input` event to pick up any change (eg paste)
- use `$("select").val("new value")` to set the value
- the "new value" must match one of the `value=` option and is case sensitive
- you can check how many characters there are by using `$("input").val().length`

For ease of testing, I've reduced the character count to 2 and 4, giving updated snippet:

```js
$("#txtFirstNo").on("input", function() {
  $("#selResult").val("");
  if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
    $("#selResult").val("aaa");
  }
  if ($(this).val().length >= 4) {
    $("#selResult").val("bbb");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" /> Result:
<select id="selResult">
  <option></option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
</select>
```

This could be slightly improved (micro-optimised) as it sets the `select` .val() multiple time, but it's ok in this case

Comment: What if I need multiple values in select tag
Example : There are two same conditions but different values, then what should be done

Comment: I already added a comment to your question regarding that

Comment: I found an existing answer that sets multiple values in a multi-value select, combined with the above, should help you get where you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49718449/2181514

Comment: If I use regular expression in if condition , then the output is not showing. So how to do it ?
Example : if ($(this).val().match(/^\d{10}$/, ''))

Comment: That should work, but only if it's exactly 10 digits from start to finish and nothing else

Comment: And can you give me simple example of using array in select tag ?

Comment: @KirthikaPillai my answer works for multiple selected options https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535641/6127393

Comment: @ Arleigh Hix  What if i want to do by array ??

Comment: @KirthikaPillai array of what?  Possible answers? Possible inputs?  "do it by array" just isn't clear enough in itself.  Please ask a new question with full clarity.

Comment: @freedomn-m  I edited the question and code. Now can you help to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple-select, it can be easier/cleaner to set the `selected` property directly on the desired option(s).

The following example uses a multiple select and overlapping conditions ('CCC' will also be selected any time the input value starts with 3 numbers).

```js
$(document).keyup(function() {
  let firstNo = $("#txtFirstNo").val();
  // first clear any previously selected options
  $('#txtResult option').prop('selected', false);
  
  if (firstNo.match(/^\d{10}$/, '')) {
    $('#txtResult option[value="aaa"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
  if (firstNo.match(/^\d{12}$/, '')) {
    $('#txtResult option[value="bbb"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
  if (firstNo.match(/^\d{3}/, '')){
    $('#txtResult option[value="ccc"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" />
Result:
<select id="txtResult" multiple>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If 2 conditions are satisfied then it should show me only two values. So how to do ??

Comment: @KirthikaPillai you'll need to provide some examples in your question (or better yet, ask a new question with clarity).   This answer already does exactly what you've just asked.

Comment: What if I want dropdown arrow rather than showing full list on screen ??

Comment: Then you can't use a `<select multiple` - that's how the browser renders them.  I would suggest something like select2 as a replacement (rather than roll your own)